# Why is Solaris big endian

Tags: unix, solaris, endian

... when Unix is little endian?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29), Solaris is based on Unix in some sense:

> In 1987, AT&T and Sun announced that they were collaborating on a project to merge the most popular Unix variants on the market at that time: BSD, System V, and Xenix. This became Unix System V Release 4 (SVR4).
>
> On September 4, 1991, Sun announced that it would replace its existing BSD-derived Unix, SunOS 4, with one based on SVR4. This was identified internally as SunOS 5, but a new marketing name was introduced at the same time: Solaris 2.

Comment: Very educational and informative  http://www.amazon.com/Microprocessors-Programmers-View-Computing-Works/dp/0070166382

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Endianness is a property of the CPU, not the operating system.  Solaris is normally big-endian because Suns used big-endian CPUs, while UNIX was originally little-endian because it ran on little-endian machines.

Today, common UNIX-derived operating systems such as Linux run on a wide variety of CPU architectures and can be either big- or little-endian depending on which architecture is in use.  (See [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/163487/linux-how-to-tell-if-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian) if you want to find out which way your *nix goes.)

Comment: In other words decisions made 20 years ago is the reason.

Comment: @Ramhoud Essentially, yes.  BUt your dates are a bit off.  The original Unix was developed in 1969, on hardware released in 1965, so closer to 50 years ago then 20.

Comment: Many processor architectures allow for selecting which endian-ness to use , e.g. ARM.

Comment: Unix was designed from the beginning to be endian neutral. Solaris is not "normally big-endian" as it supports both big and little endian architectures.

Answer (score 11):

Your assumptions are incorrect: Solaris is not big-endian, Unix is not little-endian.

Both depend on the CPU they are running on.   Solaris on a big-endian SPARC CPU is big-endian, Solaris on a little-endian Intel or AMD CPU is little-endian.   Solaris is one flavor of Unix, others similarly run either big-endian or little-endian depending on the CPU being used.